# how can I match syntax in racket?

Tags: racket

I'd like to write a macro that matches whether the given syntax is a `if` or `cond`, I tried writing it like so:

```
(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (if a b)) #'"if!"] 
    [(_ (cond a b) #'"cond!"]))
```

but it always matches the first case. How can I distinguish between the two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `syntax-case` pattern, an identifier matches anything. You already assume this to be true: when you write the pattern `(if a b)`, presumably you assume `a` will match any piece of syntax, not just the literal identifier `a`. The same is true for the `if` identifier—you’re not actually checking that the identifier is `if`, you’re just matching any piece of syntax and binding it to a pattern variable named `if`.

This is what the literals list is for. When you put an identifier in the literals list, it tells `syntax-case` to check for *that specific identifier* instead of binding a pattern variable. So you probably want this, instead:

```
(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-case stx (if cond)
    [(_ (if a b)) #'"if!"] 
    [(_ (cond a b) #'"cond!"]))
```

However, note that `syntax-case` is pretty old, and Racket has shipped with a better syntax matching library for almost a decade now, `syntax/parse`. I’d recommend it over `syntax-case` in all situations. The `syntax/parse` equivalent of the above macro looks like this:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:literals [if cond]
    [(_ (if a b)) #'"if!"] 
    [(_ (cond a b) #'"cond!"]))
```

…which is basically the same, but `syntax-parse`’s pattern language is much richer than that of `syntax-case`. For example, if you wanted to omit the `#:literals` declaration, you could annotate the individual literal patterns using `~literal`:

```
(define-syntax (foo stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ ((~literal if) a b)) #'"if!"] 
    [(_ ((~literal cond) a b) #'"cond!"]))
```

For more information, [see the documentation for `syntax/parse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html).